# How to loop with curry function

Tags: javascript

A simple app. I need to go through entries in a log.
The log contains text and level. I create entries in the log manually in the main function.
Now, I need to go through all the entries in the array of logs and print stuff (the content).
However, I need to do this with curry function.

This is the main function:

```
function main() {
    const firstLine = ['21', ';'];
    const level = '2';
    const sep = firstLine[1];
    const myLog = joinedLogger(level, sep);
    const n = 4;
    let messages = [];
    var ob = {level: 20, text: 'foo'};
    messages.push(ob);
    ob = {level: 90, text: 'bar'};
    messages.push(ob);
    console.log(messages);
    myLog(...messages);
}
```

main();

I see in the console, of course, the array with objects conatined in messages.
Now, I need to do something in the joinedLogger function. But here Im not really sure how I shoudl code it:

```
function joinedLogger(level, sep) {
    return function(arr){
        console.log('level',level);
        console.log('sep',sep);
        console.log('arr',arr);
    }
}
```

Right now, the console is printing this:

```
[ { level: 20, text: 'foo' }, { level: 90, text: 'bar' } ]
level 4
sep ;
arr { level: 20, text: 'foo' }
```

But I dont understand how to make the joinedLogger fucntion to be written in order to see all the array. And not only the first element like now.

Comment: Can you add a clearer description of inputs and desired outputs?

Comment: If your `myLog` function is expecting a single `array`, it should be called as `myLog(messages)` not `myLog(...messages)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use rest operator for that in the function that you are returning from joinedLogger function.

```
function joinedLogger(level, sep) {
return function(...arr){
    console.log('level',level);
    console.log('sep',sep);
    console.log('arr',arr);
}
}
```